# Xamarin: Getting error while building -> invalid file path 'obj\Debug\90\res\views\layouttest.xml'

Tags: c#, xamarin, build, xamarin.android

While I'm trying to build my Xamarin App, it stops everytime with the error message `"invalid file path 'obj\Debug\90\res\views\layouttest.xml'"`. I tried to delete the directory, rebuild or clean the solution and build it again. 
The error comes from the Android Project.
The file that is marked from VS is in the directory:
[Directory Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4quDD.png)

**Update**:
As Land Lu - MSFT mentioned below, was an unused file the issue. Deleting the file and rebuilding the project worked just fine!

Comment: Did you utilize it in your project? If you don't need it, try to remove it from your project. And then delete the bin/obj folders. Finally, test it again after the cleaning.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT thanks for the answer, that helped! :)

Comment: May I make this as an answer so that you could mark it to end this thread?

Comment: Yes, would be cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there is a cache file named `layouttest.xml` in your project.
Try to remove the file there if you don't need it.

Delete the bin/obj folders of your project to make a full cleaning. Finally, rebuild your project to complete the compiling.

Answer (score 4):

If you are finding this error after updating VS2019 to 16.7.2 please see the following articles:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1156349/index.html
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5052

The TLDR is that android resources now have to be present in standard folders such as Resources/layout and Resources/drawable. Using random folders within your project will generate build errors.

Just to add to the fun, I had a resource that had somehow ended up as the dependent of another file.

```
<AndroidResource Include="Main.axml">
  <DependentUpon>CanvasRenderContext.cs</DependentUpon>
</AndroidResource>
```

I had to edit the csproj file to remove the DependentUpon tag before I could move to Resources/layout folder. Hopefully you wont have an issue quite that weird.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I've encountered exactly the same situation with Main.axml and your advice saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

For those hitting this from the MAUI side as I was - my issue was that I had an image resource file that was not added to the project correctly.  Looked at the properties for the image in Solution Explorer and it was still an Android resource rather than a MAUI image.  Guess this makes sense, was migrating the image from a Xamarin Android app.  Had some lines in the project file explicitly removing it from the MAUI image category and adding it to the Android resource category.  Looked something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MauiImage Remove="Resources\Images\foo.png" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <AndroidResource Include="Resources\Images\foo.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Removed those lines and the image was correctly recognized as a MAUI image, and the issue went away.